# Sorting list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, sorting

I've got a small problem I'm struggling to solve. 
Let's say I've got an unordered list, like:

```
<ul> 
    <li> //first
       <div id="div1> text </div>
    </li>

    <li> //second
       <div id="div2> text </div>
    </li>

    <li> //third
       <div id="div3> text </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there an easy approach to change the order of this list? So, let's say, the third one would be displayed in the middle?
The problem is I've got a lot of stuff under each

and can't modify the list on the server-side since I don't have access to logic files :/

Thanks 
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know the positions you want to go in and move around you can.  Here's an example:

In this case remove the `:eq(2)` (third, 0 based) element, then insert it after the first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul li:eq(2)").remove().insertAfter($("ul li:eq(0)"));
});

<ul> 
    <li>
       <div id="div1"> first </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div id="div2"> second </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div id="div3"> third </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are a few other options as well, but the answer is **yes** you can do this.

Comment: great stuff, that's what you call K.I.S.S. method turn into practice :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using jQueryUI. there's a very nice example [here](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/)

Answer (score 0):

The TinySort plugin should sort you out [[TinySort]](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort)